# Excel - mark duplicate value and if required or not

Tags: excel

I have a data like this:

```
ID          ID-Name CountUnique Required    Available   **Results**
1-Line 1    Line 1  1           1           Y           Y
2-Line 1    Line 1  0           0           N           Y-Duplicate
3-Line 1    Line 1  0           1           N           Y-Duplicate
1-Line 2    Line 2  1           0           N           N-Duplicate
2-Line 2    Line 2  0           1           N           N
3-Line 2    Line 2  0           1           N           N-Duplicate
```

I am using excel and I want to use an if condition to determine when a ID have the same values and if it is available or not. If it has duplicates and is available, I want to have Y (for the one that is available) and Y-Duplicate in Results column for all the same ID-Names (regardless if other ID-Names are available or not) and if not available similar logic.
How can I do this for the whole sheet?

My attempts were based on the following logic. If I am able to do it for individual steps then I can combine. The issue I noticed is that I need to take into account the ID-Name and have it used.

Current formulas:

```
=IF(AND([@Available] = "Y", [@CountUnique] =1),"Y", "Y-Duplicate")
=IF(AND([@Available] = "Y", [@CountUnique] =0),"Y-Duplicate","")
=IF(AND([@Available] = "N", [@CountUnique] =1),"N", "N-Duplicate")
=IF(AND([@Available] = "N", [@CountUnique] =0),"N-Duplicate","")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use and() and a cumulative count.

Comment: Your fourth row, shouldn't it be `N` instead of `N-Duplicate` because `CountUnique` is 1? And then, fith row should be `N-Duplicate` instead of `N`, right? You need to explain better the logic behind this and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your logic properly, but just in case, note that you may benefit from you field `CountUnique`

[image]

My formula in Results is:

```
=IF(C2=1;E2;E2&"-Duplicate")
```

Comment: @foxrite - if there is npt Value in E, how to populate with Y or N?

Comment: @Kalenji Example input posted by OP does not contemplate that scenario. In that case, the formula needs to be different but I guess there is always a value in that field. Anyways, how would you manually choose Y or N if there is no value in E? Depending on that, maybe we can make a better formula.